# WebClient and WebRequest, downloading files > 4Gb

Tags: c#, http

Whenever I try to download a file from a server (the server is on a device, it's not on the interwebs) > 4Gb, the transfer only actually transfers what appears to be (FileSize) % 4Gb.  In other words, for a file just over 4.5Gb, I end up only transferring around 600mb of data.

It's something to do with content-length headers and so on I think, but I'm not sure what the exact mechanism is.  I've tried using WebClient and WebRequest but both exhibit the same behaviour.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get past this limit?  Here's my current loop:

```
 byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(transferDetails.URL));

 using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
 {
     using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
     {
         using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(actualPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
         {
             int count = 0;

             do
             {
                // Read a block.

                count = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                // Write out to the local file.

                if(count > 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
         } while (count != 0);
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried just using `DownloadFile(transferDetails.Url, actualPath)` ?

Comment: I haven't, but I want to provide "progress" feedback to the user, as from this device such files can take several minutes to transfer (ultimately it's coming over a USB 2.0 connection).

Comment: Edit: also, yes, I used DownloadAsync with WebClient and that has the same problem of the 4Gb limitation.

Comment: @Robinson - well, from IIS6 5Gb file is downloaded fine in general. So I discovered only one issue - at some point fiddler thrown out-of-memory exception and transfer stopped. Probably you should check if there is a problem with proxy. What kind of server is used, maybe limitation is there?